# How to perform statistical clustering from MongoDB database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an app that lets the user to perform searches on the platform. I have a MongoDB database with a collection where I store all the searches of all users.

The search system lets the user select a minimum of one filter and a maximum of six. Then, the user write the tags that wants to use.

After the user has selected all the filters and has written all the tags, I save this search query into a MongoDB collection. The schema where I store the searches is like the following:

```
var savedSearches = new Schema({
  filterA: { type : Array, default: [] },
  filterB: { type : Array, default: [] },
  filterC: { type : Array, default: [] },
  filterD: { type : Array, default: [] },
  filterE: { type : Array, default: [] },
  filterF: { type : Array, default: [] },
  userCountry: { type : String, default: [] },
  datetime: { type : Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

For example: "User A" performs a search with the filters A, B and D. In the filter A the user writes the tags "alpha", "beta" and "charlie"; in the filter B writes the tags "delta", "omega" and "juliet"; and in the filter D writes the tags "omega", "zulu" and "roger".

The document that I send on Mongo is, then, the following:

```
{
      filterA: ["alpha","beta","charlie"],
      filterB: ["delta","omega","juliet"],
      filterC: [],
      filterD: ["omega","zulu","roger"],
      filterE: [],
      filterF: [],
      userCountry: "Andorra",
      datetime: "2018-11-27T08:32:56.434Z"
}
```

I would like to group the most similar searches of the users, so if "User A" perform a similar search to the one performed by "User B" the two searches will be on the same group (cluster). Then, I want to use these groups to suggest similar searches to the users.

The idea is to build a statistical clustering engine so these similar searches will be grouped inside a "group", but I don't know how to start. I have tried aggregated queries, but they don't meet the requirements I need.

I have also tried to check the k-means algorithm but doesn't work well with categorical data.

Any ideas on how can i perform this clustering? Maybe using MCA and then clustering with the values returned?

Thanks in advance.